# In SQL Server, how to get number of players dropping vs. those renewing their monthly sport from start and end date

Tags: sql-server

- Start date ='2020-05-01'
- End date ='2020-10-01'

The data in SQL Server

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+
| PlayerID | AdmissionMonthID | MonthsBetweenTwoDates |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+
|        3 |                5 |                     5 |
|        3 |                6 |                     6 |
|        3 |                7 |                     7 |
|        6 |                5 |                     5 |
|        6 |                6 |                     6 |
|       10 |                5 |                     5 |
|       10 |                6 |                     6 |
|       10 |               10 |                    10 |
|       11 |                5 |                     5 |
|       11 |                6 |                     6 |
|       11 |                7 |                     7 |
|       11 |                8 |                     8 |
|       11 |                9 |                     9 |
|       11 |               10 |                    10 |
+----------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

The expected result

```
dropping 
--------
 2
 3
 6
10

renewing monthly
----------------
11
```

Comment: Column names would be helpful

Comment: i put it in the attached photo

Comment: Keep the sample data as text.  Easier for folks to copy and paste.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data

Comment: i put it in the attached photo and put it as a text

Comment: Imgur is blocked for some of us at work, I can't help you without some textual data.

Comment: Please help us in answering your question. Follow --> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/12991188

Comment: i updated the question with textual data